# Issue while using ReactiveUi routing while more than one view points to one view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, reactive-programming, reactiveui

I'm having an issue on my windows application (.NET / WPF) with trying to direct 2 of my Views to use the same ViewModel while using ReactiveUI with routing and MVVM. Application did work just fine while using separate ViewModels for each View (exept small bug - when I click the open-new-window-button after closing the first instance of that window, it crashes the app.).

As for main issue - I have a MainWindow, with UserControl that is RoutedViewHost (one per Window) and after redirecting more than one View to ViewModel it "bricks" (application starts up, and I can see a slight flash when a navigation-button is hit but nothing more happening) at last-registered view via Splat. I can see it is working, but stuck on that one view. Also it "bricks" the rerouting-buttons when directing to that ViewModel.

I was trying to follow example provided at https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Samples/tree/main/wpf/ReactiveUI.Samples.Routing, with small changes (I don't implement IViewModel interface, even when I did, it did not solve the issue I'm experiencing right now, also I use DataContext separately on each Window in their respective ViewModels).

My assumption is that it lacks some way to know what View I want to see first, but that does not explain bricked buttons (only the ones that redirect to that combined ViewModel, RoutedViewHost works fine.)

Anyway, sorry for long introduction, here is my code:

**Instancing the first Window**

```
        Main_WView = new Main_WView();
        Main_WView ??= (Main_WView)Locator.Current.GetService<IViewFor<Main_WViewModel>>();
        Main_WView.Show();
```

**MainWindow ViewModel**

```
    public class Main_WViewModel : ReactiveObject, IScreen
{
    public RoutingState Router { get; }


    public Main_WViewModel(IMutableDependencyResolver dependencyResolver = null)
    {
        Router = new RoutingState();
        dependencyResolver ??= Locator.CurrentMutable;
        RegisterVVM.RegisterMineVVM(this, dependencyResolver);

        Router.Navigate.Execute(new Main_CVM(this));
    }
}
```

**MainWindow View**

```
    public Main_WViewModel Main_WViewModel { get; protected set; }

public Main_WView()
{

    InitializeComponent();
    Main_WViewModel = new Main_WViewModel();
    DataContext = Main_WViewModel;

}
```

**Splat registration** (same for each Window)

```
   public static void RegisterMineVVM(object windowViewModel, IMutableDependencyResolver dependencyResolver)
{
    dependencyResolver.RegisterConstant(windowViewModel, typeof(IScreen));

    dependencyResolver.Register(() => new Main_C0View(), typeof(IViewFor<Main_CVM>));
    dependencyResolver.Register(() => new Main_C1View(), typeof(IViewFor<Main_CVM>));
}
```

Here is **combined ViewModel** that more than one-views want to use

```
public class Main_CVM : ReactiveObject, IRoutableViewModel
{
public string UrlPathSegment { get; protected set; }

public IScreen HostScreen { get; protected set; }


public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> BtClick_NavigateTo_Main_C0View { get; }
public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> BtClick_NavigateTo_Main_C1View { get; }


public Options_WView Options_WView = new Options_WView();
public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> BtClick_NavigateTo_Options_WView { get; }


public Main_CVM(IScreen screen)
{
    this.UrlPathSegment = this.GetType().Name;
    HostScreen = screen;

    BtClick_NavigateTo_Main_C0View = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async () => await HostScreen.Router.Navigate.Execute(new Main_CVM(HostScreen)).Select(_ => Unit.Default));
    BtClick_NavigateTo_Main_C1View = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async () => await HostScreen.Router.Navigate.Execute(new Main_CVM(HostScreen)).Select(_ => Unit.Default));

    BtClick_NavigateTo_Options_WView = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async () => Options_WView.Show());

}
}
```

Here is one of Main_C0View/Main_C1View **Views**

```
public partial class Main_C1View
{
public Main_C1View()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.WhenActivated(d =>
    {
        d(this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ViewModel).BindTo(this, x => x.DataContext));

        d(this.BindCommand(ViewModel,
            vm => vm.BtClick_NavigateTo_Main_C0View,
            view => view.BtClick_NavigateTo_Main_C0View));
        d(this.BindCommand(ViewModel,
            vm => vm.BtClick_NavigateTo_Main_C1View,
            view => view.BtClick_NavigateTo_Main_C1View));
    });
}
}
```

Xaml code for those **Views** (with simple command for buttons later on, they are not the issue)

```
<rx:ReactiveUserControl 
         x:Class="MyNamespace.Views.Main_C0View"
         x:TypeArguments="vm:Main_CVM"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:rx="http://reactiveui.net"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
```

Comment: You have two registrations for `IViewFor<Main_CVM>`. This is what ReactiveUI determines which View to show for the ViewModel, so effectively you're just replacing the existing registration with a new one. You'll need to have a unique ViewModel per View for RxUI routing.

Comment: @GlennWatson thank you for answer. I was hoping for some additional property on ViewModel that points to currently selected View (via unique URL?) and switching it. Most of my ViewModels will be really simple, literally a placeholder for navigation-button commands.

Also, there was one more question I posted - the crash when trying to re-open new window, anything comes to your mind? I belive it is connected to how windows are instantiated - MainWindow has somewhat similar issue when - when I just close Window via close button - it doesn't close app (running in background).

Comment: @GlennWatson in this example https://github.com/Asesjix/ReactiveUI.Winforms.Samples/tree/master/ReactiveUI.Winforms.Samples.Routing if you redirect 2 Views to same View model and only change ViewTitle properity in ViewModel, works about fine.  Is is not viable approach?